# Wifi stopped working after update - 18.04.4

Tags: networking, wireless, realtek-wireless

I am having a problem with the wifi in Ubuntu. After I installed an update on July 4, wireless network connection does not work anymore, although it still works in Windows. The wifi sometimes stopped working before, but I would just copy these commands into the terminal and reboot and the wifi would work again:

```
cd rtlwifi_new
sudo make clean
make
sudo make install
```

However this time when I tried it the commands do not work. After I enter >sudo make install, there is a whole bunch of text, followed by this error:

```
/home/josuehboy/rtlwifi_new/rc.c:336:11: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .alloc = rtl_rate_alloc,
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/josuehboy/rtlwifi_new/rc.c:336:11: note: (near initialization for ‘rtl_rate_ops.alloc’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

I am not sure what to do now. Does anybody know what is going on?

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -a` :

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:d723]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:8319]
Linux josuehboy-HP-Laptop-14-cf0xxx 5.3.0-62-generic #56~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:17:03 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; uname -a` terminal command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The driver from `rtlwifi_new` repo doesn't build with new kernels any more.

You need to install another driver this way:

```
sudo apt install git dkms
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw88.git
sudo dkms add ./rtw88
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

This way you won't need to re-install the driver after kernel upgrades.

You need to have a network connection to install this driver. You can use your phone, or boot with a previous kernel with grub menu to have your wireless adapter working for a while.